# BadMethodCallException: Undefined method 'getLatestBlogs'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy

Tags: php, symfony

I'm getting the following error when surfing to http://symblog.dev (prod env)
When surfing to http://symblog.dev/app_dev.php everything works fine.

error:

```
(BadMethodCallException: Undefined method 'getLatestBlogs'. The method name must 
start with either findBy or findOneBy!
```

src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Blog.php:

```
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository\BlogRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Blog
```

src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Repository/BlogRepository.php:

```
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * BlogRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class BlogRepository extends EntityRepository
```

I already cleared the cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

What am I doing wrong?

I found some people having the same problem on stackoverflow but can't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search I saw that Kernel for prod wasn't set to true in `web/app.php`.

It was:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

Now:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Comment: Changing this flag just toggles the `debug` status of the kernel. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: So although my 500 error went away, my problem is still there?